# Which word(s) should I use plural form in this sentence?

Tags: articles, parenthetical-plural

Here's a sentence in my essay:

> I am fascinated with the intersections between sciences and arts.

I'm not pretty sure does that sound natural? Should I use the plural form of 'science' and 'art' here? Do I need to add the article 'the' before 'sciences' and 'arts'? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The most natural forms to me are "the sciences and the arts" and "science and art".

Comment: @Peter Thank you!

Comment: *I am fascinated with the intersection between science and the arts.*

Comment: Especially in academics, we can sometimes consciously pluralize disciplines that are normally singular, to make some point about pluralities. E.g., if you said "... intersections between sciences of all sorts and arts of all sorts." As a musician, I frequently refer to "musics," referencing [Scott Goble's article](http://act.maydaygroup.org/articles/Goble14_3.pdf) that didn't coin the usage so much as codify it, as a shorthand for "disparate music-cultures and their contextual constructions of the notion of 'music.'"

Comment: _Intersections_ should stay plural, because there are many of them and that's fascinating; but _science_ and _art_ are both generic and anarthrous. And singular.